# What is a good format/approach for transforming a logo to a hamburger icon on hover?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

In my React project I have a collapsed sidebar menu with a logo at the top. I would like to add functionality that on hovering over the collapsed sidebar, transforms the logo to a basic hamburger menu, and then reverts back to the logo when the mouse leaves the sidebar.

I have access to a designer that could create an animated asset (e.g. GIF), but I am not sure how I would implement something like this with a GIF.

In my limited experience with animating in web projects, I feel that it would be ideal to somehow be able to use CSS animation to make the transformation but don't have the skills to make that myself and I don't think that is something that the designer can do.

I would love to make this logo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsqx9.png
Transform to a basic hamburger icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivRYk.png

- Would this be possible to implement in React with a GIF? Other animation formats?
- If CSS would be best how could I go about creating the logo in CSS?

Edit: To clarify, I'm hoping to find a way to create a smooth transition between the two. This is why I'm particularly interested in things like CSS animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code with an `Icon` instead of a `div`. I'll add the codesandbox so you can try it out.

**Updated Answer**

Code with hover to allow tranisitions. With some tweaking you can fade in the Icon using css.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className={`${isHovered ? "show" : "hide"}`}
        onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      >
        Hover over me.
      </div>
      <div
        className={`${isHovered ? "hide" : "show"}`}
        onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      >
        I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.show:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in;
}
```

**Updated sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-night-yii1zx?file=/src/styles.css:58-410

**Old Answer**

```
export default function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {isHovered ? (
        <h1 onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}>Hover true</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1 onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}>Hover false</h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Old sandbox**
The codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-water-mbtwfw?file=/src/App.js:176-579

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the suggestion! The main thing is that I am looking for more of a smooth transition between the two. Rendering based on state does work but it's an abrupt change which I am hoping to avoid

Comment: You could also use a traditional css `:hover` with transition effects.